# Reverse Engeneering - assistance with sprintf

Tags: c, assembly, reverse

So I was reversing an ELF Binary , and I noticed that it calls a "**sprintf**" function , and since my experience in C is not that good , I found that this function **converts a char buffer into a string**.

The code that I tackled using **ltrace**

```
[pid 943] sprintf("C0DE0E0E1E5250B88E06073C2DC-C11FEEF0", "%X%X%X%X-%X", 0xc0de0e0e, 0x1e5250, 0xb88e060, 0x73c2dc, 0xc11feef0) = 36
[pid 943] strcmp("C0DE0E0E1E5250B88E06073C2DC-FB21AE10", "C0DE0E0E1E5250B88E06073C2DC-C11FEEF0") = 3
[pid 943] +++ exited (status 0) +++
```

I tried to convert the hex values using python and give it a try but it didnt fulfill the **strcmp** call .

below is screenshot of Ghidra decompiler .

[image]
Anyone can explain ?

Comment: How does this code make any sense? The first parameter of sprintf is a destination buffer, not a string literal. Looks like the string literal is what the format string evaluates to...?

Comment: So what did you do?  Which value did you change?  What did the ltrace call look like afterwards?  The problem is not with `sprintf()` but with your approach to the problem.  @Lundin ltrace is showing the resultant output, it's not actually a string literal.

Comment: Yeah well anyway, `strcmp("F", "C")` isn't guaranteed to be 3. It is guaranteed to be a positive integer.

Comment: The `sprintf` call has `0xc11feef0` as last parameter, which would be written out as `"C11FEEF0"` (based on the `"%X"` format). You seem to have come up with `"FB21AE10"` instead though. Where does that come from ?

Comment: _converts a char buffer into a string_: that doesn't make much sense. You need to learn the basics of C. `sprintf` is similar to `printf`, but the output goes into a buffer instead of the terminal. There is more then enough documentation available about everywhere.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker the ELF takes one argument , and based on that the output changed .

Comment: @M.zK : I understand that, but my point was that you need to track down where that `"C11FEEF0"` vs. `"FB21AE10"` discrepancy comes from (by finding out where those 2 values come from, and how they relate to your input). There's not much more I can suggest based on the provided info.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker checkout the attached screenshot .

Comment: @M.zK : just keep tracing it back. The value in `local_6c` needs to be `0xfb21ae10`. It's calculated in the while loop before the `sprintf`call, and depends on the contents of the `__s` array. Presumably the input you give will allow you to somehow manipulate the contents of that array, and then it's your job to find out which input causes `local_6c` to evaluate to `0xfb21ae10`. Good luck !

Comment: @SanderDeDycker It turns out that it xoring multiple times , and I managed to get the right value , thanks .

Comment: @M.zK : glad to have been of assistance